# Class template overloading across TUs

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider the following C++11 application:

**A.cpp:**

```
template<typename T>
struct Shape {
    T x;
    T area() const { return x*x; }
};

int testA() {
    return Shape<int>{2}.area();
}
```

**B.cpp:**

```
template<typename T, typename U = T>
struct Shape {
    T x;
    U y;
    U area() const { return x*y; }
};
int testB() {
    return Shape<int,short>{3,4}.area();
}
```

**Main.cpp:**

```
int testA();
int testB();
int main() {
   return testA() + testB();
}
```

Although it compiles (as long as A and B are in separate TUs), it doesn't look right, and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

**Hence my Question:** Does this violate ODR, overloading, or any other rule, and if so, what sections of [the Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/) are violated and why?

Comment: putting the class in unnamed namespace would solve the issue.

Comment: ODR violation, as there is 2 template `Shape` with different definitions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is an ODR violation. [Template names have linkage](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp#4). And both those template names have external linkage, as [[basic.link]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.link) says:

> An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly
>   within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage. All other namespaces
>   have external linkage. A name having namespace scope that has not been
>   given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing
>   namespace if it is the name of
>
> - [...]
> - a template.

And on account of that, since both templates share a name, it means that [[basic.def.odr]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.def.odr#5) applies:

> There can be more than one definition of a [...] class template
>   (Clause [temp]) [...] in a program provided that each definition
>   appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions
>   satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named D
>   defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - [...]
>
> If D is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit,
>   then the preceding requirements shall apply both to names from the
>   template's enclosing scope used in the template definition
>   ([temp.nondep]), and also to dependent names at the point of
>   instantiation ([temp.dep]). If the definitions of D satisfy all these
>   requirements, then the program shall behave as if there were a single
>   definition of D. If the definitions of D do not satisfy these
>   requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

Not the same sequence of tokens by a margin.

You can easily resolve it, as [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) suggested, by putting both definitions of the templates into an unnamed namespace, thus giving them internal linkage.

Comment: But the two templates have different arguments, are they still the same template?

Comment: @RustyX - Yes, the template name itself (`Shape`) is what has the linkage. And it identifies the template definition. So you have two different template definitions with the same name, having external linkage. That's why the ODR must be considered.

Comment: Ah it seems only *function templates* may be [overloaded](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over#1). That's interesting because specializations *are* allowed, although now I see that that is mentioned separately.

Comment: @RustyX - That's solved by the first link I added in, about names. It goes in so much as to say *"Specializations (explicit or implicit) of a template that has internal linkage are distinct from all specializations in other translation units."*.